# how to reset nested object form angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I follow angular.js tutorial

I add list feature in object array and make form to add it..
I search and finally get how to add new feature to object but I don't know how to reset the form

this is the code..
http://plnkr.co/edit/O2xmL5

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you've created this variable but it's not necessarily tied to your scope... in fact, I'm not exactly sure where it's bound... perhaps `form` creates some sub-scope automatically?

Either way, I would recommend binding the `input` to a variable that your controller will have access to.  A property on `phone` seems to make the most sense.  After that, inside of `$scope.addFeature`, you can clear it out (or do whatever you want with it):

HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="addFeature(phone, phone.featureToAdd)">
    ...
    <input ... ng-model="phone.featureToAdd" ...>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.addFeature = function(phone,addfeature) {
    phone.features.push(addfeature);
    phone.featureToAdd = '';
};
```

I've implemented it here: **http://plnkr.co/edit/wWwj4F**

Comment: it works..thanks..

so is it adding object featureToAdd to phone so each phone has featureTo add?